# Fixed/Relative Positioning:

Tags: css

I am trying to make a page with two "fixed" sidebar images, and a "fixed" header image.  Since the header is fixed (0 to 10% from the top).  I do not want the header image to overlap with any text on the page.  I tried positioning the paragraph tag as "relative", and setting it 10% from the top, but the image still overlaps with the text.  How can I solve this problem?

Here's what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/KSz59/

```
.header {
    width: 70%;
    height: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: -1;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Add some code or recreate the issue on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: add `margin-top: 10%` to `body`

Comment: Give the paragraph a margin-top of 10%

Comment: @Huangism I would, but I don't know how to upload images onto jsfiddle

Comment: Use placeholder images from sites like placehold.it and placekitten.com.

Comment: Use `<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">`. Just change the width(350) and height(150) as required.

Comment: Here's a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSz59/

Comment: I have edited the question, please reopen it...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/D6ANw/ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current setup, you would have to position the p absolutely

http://jsfiddle.net/KSz59/2/

```
p {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you have more content then it's better to replace the `p` with a content div and put everything in the div